# EFQ propertyCondition Doesn't work in Simpletest

Tags: testing, database

This Entity Field Query works as expected outside of simpletest:

```
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->fieldCondition('field_exhibition_window_start', 'value', $date, '<=')
  ->fieldCondition('field_exhibition_window_end', 'value', $date, '>=')
  ->addTag('DANGEROUS_ACCESS_CHECK_OPT_OUT')
  ->propertyCondition('status', '0');
```

Inside of a simpletest, after the creation of an unpublished node within specified parameters, it unexpectedly returns zero results.

However, if I comment out this line:

```
  ->propertyCondition('status', '0');
```

(and put a semicolon on the line above) then the query works as expected and returns a node ID. I've even done a node_load() on the node ID returned and inspected the node to be sure that it is, in fact, at that exact moment in time, unpublished.

My simpletest has a user with node access bypass permissions, and I'm using `DANGEROUS_ACCESS_CHECK_OPT_OUT`, so it doesn't seem like a permissions issue.

Does Simpletest do something weird with EFQs? Why isn't it finding my unpublished node?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the status of my node was, in fact, being set to '1' immediately prior to this query running, but that despite the fact that the `node_save()` that was called immediately after `node_publish_action()` should have cleared the cache, `node_load()` was in fact calling a cached version of the node.

I got around this by adding the `TRUE` parameter to `node_load()`.

NOTE: You can't skip the middle parameter, á la `node_load($nid, TRUE)`. This is annoying, because it will fail silently and it will just return a boolean FALSE. To get a node without caching, and also without specifying a VID, you must use `node_load($nid, NULL, TRUE)`.

In a simpletest, you can also use a `TRUE` parameter like so:  `drupalWebTestCase::drupalGetNodeByTitle($nid, TRUE)`.